# Error accessing field by reflection for persistent property

Tags: java, hibernate

i got this error on my hibernate

```
Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer br.com.moldargesso.moldar.entities.Cidade.id] by reflection for persistent property [br.com.moldargesso.moldar.entities.Cidade#id] : 1
```

Class obra

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "obras")
public class Obra {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn (name = "fk_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "fk_cidade")
    private Cidade cidade;
```

Class CIDADE

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "cidade")
public class Cidade {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String nome;
```

DAO

public List list(Integer cidade){

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Obra.class);

    if(cidade != null){

        criteria.add(Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.eq("cidade", cidade)));
    }

    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
    List<Obra> obraList = criteria.list();
    session.close();
    return obraList;
}
```

I don't know how to fix it, i'm a begginer and i'd like to fix it.
Could someone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't have get/setter for `Cidade` class, so when framework init your class or doing set value to it's field it will throw this error.

Comment: It was generated.